# Click event fired before clicked on Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I have a click event properly fired on IE and Chrome, but not on Firefox.

My code:

```
sender.bind("open", function () {
    var $openButton = sender.wrapper.find('.k-i-arrow-s');
    $openButton.addClass('active');

    $(document).delegate($openButton, "click", function () {
        sender.close();
        sender.input.blur();
    });
});
```

The problem is that the **delegate** on Firefox is fired at the very first time when click event is registered! I also have tried **on()** and **bind()** and the same happened.

Explaining the code:

It's a Kendo MultiSelect control. When it opens I have to register a click event to **$openButton** object, that's all.

Any idea?

Here is the dojo: http://dojo.telerik.com/eSOBo

To test click on the arrow!

Best regards

Daniel

Comment: so have you tried using setTimeout, or maybe using some kind of variable flag.. e.g if isOkToDelegate then do delegate..

Comment: no @DionDirza, I wish to fix this properly.

Comment: could you make a fiddle or dojo?

Comment: I updated the thread with the dojo! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look to your code and its full of unnecessary code

```
sender.input.after($openButton);
```

line 52, 59 you always insert the same content, you already put the arrow in line 46 with the same code, you won't need this anymore.

Binding `close` and `open` for multiselect to add and remove active class in arrow, that is something that ruin your expected behaviour. I suggest you read [**"What is event bubbling and capturing?"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing).

The moment you click on arrow or multiselect textbox normally (all browser **should have** same behaviour) event capturing will work the same, start with multiselect open then arrow click event. 
Yet this jquery code `after` which re-insert the element content, give you different experience in firefox with the rest browser. Try remove that code and see what happen with all browser.

Check out this [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@diondirza/oYoPe) to see a simpler implementation yet supported with all browser.

Comment: This was the solution! Thanks @DionDirza